# does anyone know what this is called is it a drawer, a stage, or a shelf?

Tags: panel, desktop, indicator

[The bit below the panel on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfoxq.jpg)

I am looking to see if anyone knows what I would call this. I'm sure the panel contains a places/placesmenu indicator, but would it be a drawer, stage, or shelf thingy, as a part of the indicator, or the panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing which you are looking for is known as **Inner Navigator panel** or just a **Navigator panel**.

Comment: Would that be a part of the indicator or the panel?

Comment: It is the child container of panel placeholder(If you know about the inheritance)

Comment: Just a bit of wrong. It would have been a drop down applet if it would have been a panel of any particular application. Refer this picture for better insight: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-S5ZtDcYQN_c/URQeO39cXII/AAAAAAAANf4/1LAJbe9FRf0/s1600/kde-nautilus-appmenu.png